# Suppose that $P$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ in one variable with real coefficients and $K$ a real number.Then which is /are true?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $P$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ in one variable with real coefficients and $K$ a real number.Then which is /are true?

1. If $n$ is even and $K>0$ , then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
2. If $n$ is odd and $K<0$ , then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
3. For any natural number $n$, and $0<K<1$ then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
4. If $n$ is odd and $K \in \mathbb{R}$ , then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.

---

I feel that Rolles Theorem will be helpful but cant apply i. Can i get some help please.

Comment: In all those cases, consider $x\mapsto P(x)-Ke^x$. Is this function continuous? What is its limit when $x\to +\infty$? $-\infty$?